# aligning horizontal label with grid lines in a graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dictionary:

```
x = {'Benchmark': {'credit': -1.19,
  'dividend': 0.95,
  'fi_hy': 1.67,
  'fi_ig': 1.0,
  'growth': 0.9,
  'large-cap': 1.0,
  'mid-cap': 0.79,
  'small-cap': 0.63,
  'momentum': 0.9,
  'quality': 0.99,
  'total market': 0.98,
  'value': 0.97,
  'volatility': 1.16},
 'Portfolio': {'credit': -1.2434,
  'dividend': 1.0128000000000001,
  'fi_hy': 1.8062999999999998,
  'fi_ig': 0.868,
  'growth': 0.9530000000000001,
  'large-cap': 1.0441000000000003,
  'mid-cap': 0.8832,
  'small-cap': 0.7126,
  'momentum': 0.9372,
  'quality': 1.0342000000000002,
  'total market': 1.0383,
  'value': 1.0238,
  'volatility': 1.1582}}
```

i converted the dictionary to a dataframe and plotted the result:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=figsize)
df = pd.DataFrame(x)
df.plot(kind='bar', ax=ax,color=['#0574A0','#FF5233'], rot=35)
```

[image]

All good. However, i want to be able to get the label correct where "credit" the letter "t" ends on the first line.  "dividend" the letter "d" ends on 2nd line etc.  How do i do this here?  Thanks

Comment: let me know if that helps

Comment: yes it did immensely.  thanks a lot.  sometimes i don't know how to type what im looking for

Comment: Your post now helps to gather additional searches and points them to the duplicate.  It's expected (-:  Glad you got what you needed.